# VS2019 shows a notification for an Update but VSIX Extension installer says update already installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

In my latest version `16.9.3` of `VS2019`, I get following notification for an update to an extension (figure 1 below). And when I click on `UPDATE` button I get the message that update will be installed after I close all windows of `VS2019`. After I close `VS2019`, the `VSIX Extension installer` starts but gives me the following message (figure 2 below). It is happening since yesterday, and the notification keeps showing whenever I open `VS2019`. **Question**: What does this mean - do I already have the latest version of the extension or something else is going on, because (as figure 1 shows) I have older version and that I do keep getting the notification for an updated version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the same error. After installing "twice" to see if it was a fluke, I just ignored the message by clicking the 'X'.

Comment: @Casey I have not yet dismissed the message because the update dialog (shown in figure 1 above) is showing current version of the extension to be older than the new updated version. If there is a way to find out the actual version number of the extension, and it turns out to be in fact the latest version, I will dismiss the update notification message.

Comment: There is already a [bug report](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Rich-Navigation-detects-U/1389718) about it on microsoft's feedback system.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for pointing out to the link. After reading your comment, I have just scheduled the update to the newer version `0.1.262.1172`  (instead of `0.1.259.60780` that was giving the wrong notification).

Comment: As of this comment they pushed a newer update that installs successfully.